# how to databind a comboboxcolumn on a datagridview with databind

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagridview on my project, and this is the code of my datagridview:

```
  With DataGridView1
             .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
             .ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single
             .CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single
             .GridColor = Color.Black
 
             .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
             .MultiSelect = False
             .AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
             .AllowUserToAddRows = False
             .ReadOnly = True
 
             .AutoGenerateColumns = False
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("cod_produto").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("nome_produto").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("descricao").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("qtd_existente").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("qtd_minima").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("precounitario_venda").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("nome_fornecedor").Visible = True
              Me.DataGridView1.Columns("categoria_produto").Visible = True
          end with
          Dim listaproduto As List(Of Produto) = CAD.CAD_Listar.ObterProduto()
  
          Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = listaproduto
         DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

now I wanted to create another column containing a combobox which I did here

```
    Dim lstcategoria As List(Of CategoriaProduto) = CAD.CAD_Listar.ObterCategoria()

        Dim comboboxColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        With comboboxColumn
            .DataSource = lstcategoria
            .DisplayMember = "categoriaproduto"
            .ValueMember = "cod_categoriaproduto"
        End With
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboboxColumn)
```

but this is not working, it does not throw any exception but the combobox just stays with no items. I know the list is working because if I create a normal combobox (not in a comboboxcolumn) the combobox fills with the values of the list. but for some reason when I try to do the same but in a `comboboxcolumn` it just does not fill. Can someone help me on this? thanks

Comment: You will need to set the DataPropertyName for the DataGridViewComboBox besides the properties already set.

Comment: I'd suggest adding your column(s) in the designer rather than in code.  It may be worth your while to check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476-NET-2-0-Adding-a-ComboBox-Column-to-a-DataGridView&highlight=